# Оптимизация MySql запроса: count, orderBy, groupBy

Tags: mysql, оптимизация, оптимизация-запросов

столкнулась с проблемой оптимизации следующего запроса.

```
SELECT cs.id, cs.parent_id, cs.name, cs.name_rus
     , cs.description, cs.type_category, cs.url, cs.title
     , cs.meta_title, cs.meta_keywords, cs.meta_description
     , cs.image, cs.visible, cs.position, cs.percent1, cs.percent2
     , cs.is_can_liked, cs.product_percent, cs.country_id
     , COUNT( v.id ) AS prod_count
     , co.name
FROM categories cs
LEFT JOIN prod_categories pc ON pc.category_id = cs.id
LEFT JOIN prod ps ON ps.id = pc.product_id
                     AND ps.visible
LEFT JOIN countries co ON cs.country_id = co.id
                          AND country_id <> 0
LEFT JOIN variants v ON ps.id = v.product_id 
                    AND (v.stock > 0 
                         OR (v.stock IS NULL AND v.st_custom = 1))
GROUP BY cs.id
ORDER BY cs.position
```

Прикладываю скрин EXPLAIN'а.

[image: скрин explain запроса]

Возможно ли как-то ещё оптимизировать запрос? Перепробовала различные индексы и зашла в тупик :(
На данном этапе запрос выдает у меня 5935 строк за 1,5-1,6 сек.

Comment: `count()` в подзапросе посчитайте и его результаты приджойньте, уберите группировку из основного запроса вовсе

Comment: И в условиях связывания перепишите OR на AND.